# Are there database design types or models that are referred to as numbers

Tags: database, database-design, database-schema, olap, oltp

In database design, either OLAP or OLTP, are there designs/types that are referred to as numbers like 2,3,7,13 etc.?

Kind of similar to 1st, 2nd, 3rd normal form, in the way they are described.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I've been doing off-and-on reading within the database industry for over 10 years, and I've never heard of any such -- but that's just my experience.

If there are any such naming conventions, I'm fairly sure they'd be industry-specific, or product-specific, or perhaps just book- or magazine article-specific.